# Shrinkage effects in a hierarchical model

Tags: posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, regularization

I am working on the chimpanzees dataset from Richard McElreath's text, "Statistical Rethinking", edition 2.

I have built 2 simple models, one a fixed effects model and the other a hierarchical model.

```
library(modelr)
library(gridExtra)
library(rethinking)
data(chimpanzees)
d <- chimpanzees

rm(chimpanzees)
detach(package:rethinking, unload = T)
library(brms)

d$treatment <- 1 + d$prosoc_left + 2 * d$condition
d$treatment <- as.factor(d$treatment)
d$pulled_left <- as.factor(d$pulled_left)
d$actor <- as.factor(d$actor)
d$block <- as.factor(d$block)
```

The pulled_left fraction in the dataset as per the different actors is

[image: Plot for actors]

As we can see, the actor #2 always pulls left.

The first fixed effects model

```
priors <- c(prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = b))

bm_11.4 <- brm(data = d, family = bernoulli,
          formula = pulled_left ~ 1 + actor + treatment,
          sample_prior = T, prior = priors,
          cores = 4, chains = 4)
```

Another, a hierarchical model

```
bm_11.5 <- brm(data = d, family = bernoulli,
          formula = pulled_left ~ 1 + (1|actor) + (1|treatment),
          sample_prior = T, #prior = priors,
          cores = 4, chains = 4,
          control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95))
```

When I take a look at the predictions based on the posterior draws using the following code

```
p1 <- d %>%
        data_grid(actor, treatment) %>%
        add_fitted_draws(bm_11.4) %>%
        median_qi(.value) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = .value, y = treatment)) + geom_pointintervalh() + facet_wrap(actor~.) +
          ggtitle("Fixed Effects model")

p2 <- d %>%
        data_grid(actor, treatment) %>%
        add_fitted_draws(bm_11.5) %>%
        median_qi(.value) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = .value, y = treatment)) + geom_pointintervalh() + facet_wrap(actor~.) +
          ggtitle("Random effects model")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

Now, I plot the predictions from both the models as shown below:

[image: Fixed Vs Hierarchical model predictions]

For the actor #2, the chimpanzee always pulls the left level and hence the probability of pulling the left level is closer to 1, in both the models. However, given the shrinkage I expected that the hierarchical model would be pulled away from 1 and not the fixed effects model. I would like to understand this behavior, please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have commented out (`#`) the set priors for the hierarchical model, but not the fixed effects model. You have also set `sample_prior = TRUE`, even though this is incompatible with improper priors, [including the default ones](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.10.0/topics/brm). Could you elaborate on these choices?

Comment: 1. I am setting sample_prior to TRUE to understand the visualize the priors once the model fit is complete. 2. I have commented out the prior for the hierarchical model, as my understanding is that in brms, the group level priors are normal and there isn't flexibility to add a different prior (except for the standard deviation).

Answer (score 2):

Not all group effects in a hierarchical model are shrunk equally.

One factor which determines how much a group estimate is shrunk towards the population estimate is how much data we have from that group. Broadly — more data, less shrinkage. (The choice of prior plays a role too but I don't look at the priors in my answer.)

The estimate of a group with many observations will be shrunk less than the estimate of a group with few observations: when we have a lot of data about a group we learn about that group directly from its data; there is less "information borrowing" from other groups.

Now let's look at the chimpanzees data. There are 72 observations per actor (chimpanzee), 18 under each of 4 treatments.

To demonstrate how shrinkage decreases as we collect more data about actor 2, I sub-sample the data starting with 1 data point per treatment all the way up to 18. (Throughout I keep all the data for the other six actors.)

Here is the posterior probability that actor 2 (the chimpanzee which always ended up pressing the level) presses the lever under the L/N treatment (food on the left, no partner).

Notice that when there are very few observations of actor 2, the random effect estimate is shrunk more than the fixed effect estimate, in agreement with the OP's expectation. Once we gather more observations, the difference between the two estimates disappears. Of course, the prior specification makes a difference too, but with more data, the likelihood becomes more informative about the parameter than the prior.

[image]

---

This is the R code I used to fit the fixed-effects and random-effects models with [`brms`](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) 2.20.4.

```r
library("brms")
library("tidybayes")
library("tidyverse")

data(chimpanzees, package = "rethinking")

d <- chimpanzees %>%
  mutate(
    treatment = case_when(
      prosoc_left == 0 & condition == 0 ~ "R/N",
      prosoc_left == 1 & condition == 0 ~ "L/N",
      prosoc_left == 0 & condition == 1 ~ "R/P",
      prosoc_left == 1 & condition == 1 ~ "L/P"
    ),
    across(c(actor, block, treatment), as.character)
  ) %>%
  select(
    actor, block, treatment, pulled_left
  )

treatments <- unique(d$treatment)
treatments

prep_data <- function(k) {
  set.seed(1)
  bind_rows(
    d %>% filter(actor != "2"),
    d %>% filter(actor == "2") %>% group_by(treatment) %>% slice_sample(n = k)
  )
}

fit_fixef_model <- function(dat) {
  # Omit the intercept even though there are two categorical predictors.
  # `y ~ 0 + x1 + x2` works when there is a single categorical predictor
  # but not with two or more categorical predictors.
  model <- bf(
    pulled_left ~ x1 + x2,
    x1 ~ 0 + actor,
    x2 ~ 0 + treatment,
    nl = TRUE
  )
  # The prior also makes a difference; here I use the prior in Rethinking.
  prior <- c(
    prior(normal(0, 1.5), class = b, nlpar = x1),
    prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = b, nlpar = x2)
  )
  brm(
    model,
    prior = prior,
    family = bernoulli,
    data = dat
  )
}

fit_ranef_model <- function(dat) {
  model <- bf(
    pulled_left ~ x1 + x2,
    x1 ~ 0 + (1 | actor),
    x2 ~ 0 + treatment,
    nl = TRUE
  )
  # I use the same normal prior for the random effects even though
  # in practice we cannot compare a normal prior on "fixed" coefficients `b`
  # to a half-normal prior on the variance of "random" effects.
  prior <- c(
    prior(normal(0, 1.5), class = sd, nlpar = x1),
    prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = b, nlpar = x2)
  )
  brm(
    model,
    prior = prior,
    family = bernoulli,
    data = dat
  )
}

make_epred <- function(fit) {
  tibble(
    treatment = treatments,
    actor = "2"
  ) %>%
    add_epred_draws(fit) %>%
    median_qi(.epred)
}

# Vary k from 1 to 18
dat <- prep_data(k = 3)

fit.fe <- fit_fixef_model(dat)
fit.re <- fit_ranef_model(dat)

epred.fe <- make_epred(fit.fe)
epred.re <- make_epred(fit.re)
```